# Wordpress does not translate

Tags: translation

I have a Wordpress site (Version 4.8.3).

I wanna have the backend and frontend in German (Deutsch).

I switched in `Settings -> General Settings -> Site language` to `german`.

[image]

I have added `define('WPLANG', 'de_DE');` to my wp-config.php

And these language files in my `wp-content/languages/` folder present:

[image]

But everything stays in "english"... Can someone tell me why?

**Did I miss something?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does get_option("WPLANG") return? What is the option WPLANG in wp_options set to? Have you checked whether there is a filter that runs on `option_WPLANG`?

Comment: ``get_option("WPLANG")``returns ``de_DE`` and "option_WPLANG" does not appear anywhere in the code.

Comment: That's strange. Have you made sure .mo and .po files are actually the german language files, not just renamed english files? Any related plugins installed (WPML etc)? Have you tried disabling them?